# Need a local storage value to increase on button press

Tags: javascript, count, local-storage, calculator

I need to save a value into localstorage thats already in localstorage and only increase that by 1

**Save:**

```
function checkklaar2() {
    a = document.getElementById("eindgetal2").value;
    if (a == "0") {
        window.location.href = 'winnaar2.html';
        var gewonnen2 = localStorage.getItem("setsgewonnen2");
        localStorage.setItem("setsgewonnen2.2", gewonnen2.value + "1");
    } else {}
}
```

**View:**

```
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result1.1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("naamspeler1.1");
    document.getElementById("result2.1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("naamspeler2.1");
    document.getElementById("result1.2").value = localStorage.getItem("setsgewonnen1.2");
    document.getElementById("result2.2").value = localStorage.getItem("setsgewonnen2.2");
    document.getElementById("sets").value = localStorage.getItem("setstespelen");
    document.getElementById("sets2").value = localStorage.getItem("setstespelen");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

Inputs on receive because it is not showing the value in the inputs on page 2:

**HTML:**

```
<h1 style="margin-left:15px;">Speler<div id="result1.1"></div> </h1>
<div class="list-block">
    <ul>
        <div class="list-block">
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div class="item-title label">Sets gewonnen</div>
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="number" id="result1.2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>


            </ul>
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div class="item-title label">Sets totaal</div>
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="number" id="sets">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-left:15px;">Speler <div id="result2.1"></div></h1>
<div class="list-block">
    <ul>
        <div class="list-block">
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div class="item-title label">Sets gewonnen</div>
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="number" id="result2.2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>


            </ul>
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <div class="item-title label">Sets totaal</div>
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="number" id="sets2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("setsgewonnen2.2", parseInt(gewonnen2.value) + 1);
```

As normaly locall storage store everything as a string

Comment: True, so `gewonnen2` won't have a `value` property either since `gewonnen2 = localStorage.getItem("setsgewonnen2")`